# Как сделать зависимые пропсы в компоненте? [React] [TypeScript]

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Есть компонент, он принимает поля `type` и `users`.
Как сделать так, чтобы в зависимости от `type`, поле `users` было обязательным.
Например если type `required`, то тогда `users` обязательно нужно передавать в компонент. А если `type !== required` то тогда `users` не нужно передавать в компонент.

```
interface iCard {
   type: 'required' | 'not-required;
   users: iUsers[];
}

const Card: React.FC<iCard> = ({ type, users }) => {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
interface ICardRequired {
  type: 'required';
  users: iUsers[];
}

interface ICardNotRequired {
  type: 'not-requiered';
  users?: iUsers[];
}

type Props = ICardRequired | ICardNotRequired


const Card: React.FC<Props> = ({type, users}) => {
   ...
}
```

**UPD**
Подобный вопрос уже был задана на англоязычной версии stackoverflow

Ознакомиться с ответами вы можете здесь:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58630750/react-typescript-component-with-two-different-prop-interfaces

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]